# Listview inside viewpager with reload values

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I would like to create a ViewPager with 2 items and each of its views is contains listview. when I swipe from one page to another, each time listview getting refresh. I need to refresh only one time. Means if once load values to list view, then I swipe to the next page it need not reload to again. I need to show already load values to list view

code

```
public class ViewpagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context _context;
public static int totalPage=2;

public ViewpagerAdapter(Context applicationContext,
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager); 
    _context=applicationContext;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = new Fragment();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        f= FirstFragment.newInstance(_context);
        break;
    case 1:
        f= SecondFragment.newInstance(_context);
        break;
    }
    return f;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalPage;
}}
```

FirstFragment

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


private Context context;
private List<Historyitem> historyitems;
HistoryRecycleListAdapter historyadapter;
Handler mHandler;

ListView hisrecyclerview;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
    return f;
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstfragment, null);

    context = getActivity();
    hisrecyclerview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.hisrecyclerview);  
    LoadHistoryInitiate();     
    return view;
}

public void LoadHistoryInitiate() throws IllegalStateException{

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            historyitems = new ArrayList<Historyitem>();
            historyitems.clear();
        };
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


                final List<NameValuePair> list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String json = reader.readLine();


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if(jsonObj.has("values")){

                        JSONArray feedArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("values");
                        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                            final Historyitem item = new Historyitem();

                            if(feedObj.has("Reported_Time")){
                                if(!feedObj.getString("Reported_Time").replaceAll(" ", "").equals("")){
                                    item.setReported_Time(feedObj.getString("Reported_Time"));
                                }
                            }
                            historyitems.add(item);

                        }
                    }else{
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println(historyitems.size());
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                        historyadapter = new HistoryRecycleListAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(),historyitems);
                        hisrecyclerview.setAdapter(historyadapter);
                        hisrecyclerview.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                        hisrecyclerview.setAdapter(historyadapter);
                                       }
            }, 1000);
        };
    }.execute();
}  }
```

Second Fragment

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
private Context context;
private List<Loaditem> loaditems;
RecycleListAdapter loadadapter;
Handler mHandler;

ListView recyclerview;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
    return f;
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondfragment, null);

    context = getActivity();
    recyclerview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);  
    LoadInitiate();     
    return view;
}

public void LoadInitiate() throws IllegalStateException{

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            loaditems = new ArrayList<Loaditem>();
            loaditems.clear();
        };
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


                final List<NameValuePair> list=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

                final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String json = reader.readLine();


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if(jsonObj.has("values")){

                        JSONArray feedArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("values");
                        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                            final Loaditem item = new Loaditem();

                            if(feedObj.has("Time")){
                                if(!feedObj.getString("Time").replaceAll(" ", "").equals("")){
                                    item.setReported_Time(feedObj.getString("Time"));
                                }
                            }
                            loaditems.add(item);

                        }
                    }else{
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch(NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println(historyitems.size());
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                        loadadapter = new RecycleListAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(),loaditems);
                        recyclerview.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
                        recyclerview.setAdapter(loadadapter);
                                       }
            }, 1000);
        };
    }.execute();
}  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest solution would be `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` set it to your viewPager.

Comment: when i swipe each time its reload list view values.I need to load only once.

Comment: by calling this viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); it guarantee*  that the fragments wont be calling their onCreateView again unless if you decided too.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, Use below method inside your Activity:

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) 

Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.
```

Add below line after your ViewPager instantiation

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)
```